# insert data into database using php

Tags: php

Hi please I am trying to insert data from a url into my data base when I enter data directly, it works but when I try to use the url method it stops working.

Can u please help look through the code and c what i am doing wrong

Heres my code:

```
$flight_Number = $_GET['FlightNumber'];
$arrival_Status = $_GET['ArrivalStatus'];
$recipient_Email = $_GET['EmailAddress'];

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

***mysql_query("INSERT INTO landed (priKey, flightNumber, arrivalStatus, recipientEmail, confirmStatus)
VALUES ('', '".$flight_Number."','".$arrival_Status."', '".$recipient_Email"' ,'')");***

#mysql_query("INSERT INTO landed (priKey, flightNumber, arrivalStatus, recipientEmail, confirmStatus)
#VALUES ( '', '$_GET[FlightNumber]','$_GET[ArrivalStatus]','$_GET[EmailAddress]', '')");

#mysql_query("INSERT INTO landed (priKey, flightNumber,arrivalStatus, recipientEmail, confirmStatus)
#VALUES ( '', 'AK81','Landed', 'soulreaver19802001@yahoo.com', '')");

echo "Database updated with: " .$flight_Number. " ".$arrival_Status.;

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? I can't help notice you have 3 * on the mysql_query line, and you lack the initialization of $con. Can you please give us the full script?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `.` after `$recipient_Email`.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO landed (priKey, flightNumber, arrivalStatus, recipientEmail, confirmStatus)
    VALUES ('', '".$flight_Number."','".$arrival_Status."', '".$recipient_Email."' ,'')")
```

Escape variables using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) otherwise query will if any other variable contain single quote in it and your queries are inviting someone for [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to do this from a form, does your form use `method="get"`, or `method="post"`?  If it's using POST, you need to change your PHP from $_GET to $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this update helps you.

```
function mysqlConnect($host, $user, $password, $database) {
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($database, $con);
}

mysqlConnect('localhost','root','123456','transport_db');

$flight_Number = isset($_GET['FlightNumber']);
$arrival_Status = isset($_GET['ArrivalStatus']);
$recipient_Email = isset($_GET['EmailAddress']);

$flight_Number = mysql_real_escape_string($flight_Number);
$arrival_Status = mysql_real_escape_string($arrival_Status);
$recipient_Email = mysql_real_escape_string($recipient_Email);

$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO landed (priKey, flightNumber, arrivalStatus,       recipientEmail, confirmStatus)
VALUES ('', '$flight_Number','$arrival_Status', '$recipient_Email' ,'')") or die('Could not insert record:'.mysql_error());

if($results)
{
echo "Database updated with: $flight_Number $arrival_Status.";
}
mysql_close($con);
```